# Wordpress & hospital - what is the best way to add departments and their specializations

Tags: wordpress, divi

I work in a hospital and I participate in the creation of our new website.

We have nearly 40 departments, and each has 1 to 10 specialties. For each specialty, we would like to have 3 to 10 pages to describe in detail what the hospital offers our patients.

My question is: **what do you think is the best way to create these pages**?

- Do I have to create simple pages and just take care about the
  hierachy between them?
- Do I have to go through new content types?
- Do I have to go through a module that I have not yet found that allows me to obtain this?

Thank you in advance for the leads you can give me!

Long live the Stackoverflow community! : D

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to create custom post type and taxonomies for your goal. You can go with pages too but that have its own restrictions such as having archive,defining own single pages, taxonomy pages etc. If you want to have custom fields its also good practice to keep them for your specific post type otherwise could get messy realy quick. Also create your functions with ability to be edited in future. This will take a bit of time to code it but in future will save you much more time. And add comments!!! in your theme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) 
It seems that I am not familiar enough with the notions of content type. I return to my studies to learn this. If you have any advice, I'm interested :)

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/ is your best friend :)

Answer (score 0):

To make your Work Easy and Fast use Pre Made Divi Child Theme. You can just Edit it using Drag & Drop Option. Below are Some Example which May Help you

[Medical Fusion](https://divithemecenter.com/product/medical-fusion-multipurpose-divi-child-theme/)
[Divi Smile](https://divithemecenter.com/product/divi-smile-divi-dentist-child-theme/)

If you don't know how to edit feel free to ask us [Tech Gigs](https://tech-gigs.co.in/contact/)